# ViewPager setCurrentItem not smooth

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-transitions

I have an activity that contains one ViewPager (nothing else). The fragments I use are extremely simple. They consist of a flat background with two buttons (back and forward).

When the ViewPager scrolls with user input it works smoothly. However, when I program the buttons to use setCurrentItem to the next page the animation is really choppy.

The "choppyness" is only the first time the animation executes. After that, if I go back and forth using the buttons the animation is smooth.

Because of this behavior, I imagine that it has something to do with the way that PageViewer anticipates user behavior. If anyone can shed some light on this matter that would be of great help. Thanks!

I read about similar issues with PageViewer animations being choppy (all of them more than 3 years old). I tried their suggestions and could not get it to work; so I decided to create a new question.

Here is the code I am using:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.Listener {

    private ViewPager _pager;
    private PagerAdapter _adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        _pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        _adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getFragmentManager());
        _pager.setAdapter(_adapter);
    }

    public void next() {
        if(_pager.getCurrentItem() + 1 >= _adapter.getCount()) return;
        _pager.setCurrentItem(_pager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
    }

    public void previous() {
        if(_pager.getCurrentItem() - 1 < 0) return;
        _pager.setCurrentItem(_pager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final int PAGES = 3;

    private ArrayList<Fragment> _slides;

    public MyAdapter(MainActivity l, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        _slides = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < PAGES; i++) {
            MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
            f.addListener(l);
            _slides.add(f);
        }
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) { return _slides.get(position); }

    public int getCount() { return _slides.size(); }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Listener {
        void next();
        void previous();
    }

    private ArrayList<Listener> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addListener(Listener l) { ls.add(l); }

    protected void next() { for(Listener l : ls) l.next(); }
    protected void previous() { for(Listener l : ls) l.previous(); }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255)));

        Button bNext = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                next();
            }
        });

        Button bPrevious = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_previous);
        bPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                previous();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_previous"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="previous" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom view pager class by extending `ViewPager`
2. Override the `smoothScrollTo(...)` method

   `void smoothScrollTo(int x, int y, int v) {
       super.smoothScrollTo(x, y, 1);
   }`

The default value used is 0. When you pass 1, scrolling is smooth.

Comment: You can't call super.smoothScrollTo(x, y, 1); because it is not a public method of ViewPager, it is protected. So it can only be accessed from within the package of ViewPager.